# How to write SQL subqueries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a requirement where I need to get unique records count from one table with like search on the columns.

Here is the code:

```
Select 
    s1.so_number
from
(
Select (billto_name) As so_number 
from dbo.lamp_bookings 
where billto_name Like '%government%' or billto_name Like '%gov%' 
Union
Select (shipto_name) As so_number 
from dbo.lamp_bookings 
where shipto_name Like '%government%' or shipto_name Like '%gov%' 
Union
Select (soldto_name) As so_number 
from dbo.lamp_bookings
where soldto_name Like '%government%' or soldto_name Like '%gov%'
Union 
Select (end_user) As so_number
from dbo.lamp_bookings
where end_user Like '%government%' or end_user Like '%gov%'
) s1
```

I need to get distinct count from bookings either `soldto_name` or `shipto_name` or `billto_name` or `end_user` like (government, govt.,)

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I'm going to assume `sql server` since they included `dbo`.  With that said, sample data and expected results would be very helpful.

Comment: You need `COUNT (DISTINCT s1.so_number)`.

Comment: "government" contains "gov", so any string matching `LIKE '%government%'` also matches `LIKE '%gov%'`. You can shorten you `WHERE` clauses to `WHERE <column> LIKE '%gov%'`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one option that might be easier to manage using `unpivot` and `count` with `distinct`:

```
select count(distinct u.field)
from lamp_bookings
unpivot
(
  field
  for fields in (billto_name, shipto_name, soldto_name, end_user)
) u
where u.field like '%gov%'
```

Also you can remove your 2nd `where` criteria -- if you are checking for `gov`, no need to check for `government` as well.

- [Condensed Online Demo](http://rextester.com/JJJB96154)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unpivot option works but there are almost 8 words i need to use search criteria and either any of these 8 searches exists it should return only one count. distinct records need be counted at last

Comment: @Harry - Just use `or` for each word you need to search - `where u.field like '%gov%' or u.field like '%blah%' or ...`

Answer (score 1):

I would unpivot using `values` and then apply the logic:

```
select distinct v.so_number
from dbo.lamp_bookings b cross apply
     (values (billto_name), (shipto_name), (soldto_name), (end_user)
     ) v(so_number)
where v.so_number like '%government%' or v.so_number Like '%gov%' ;
```

If you just need the count, then use:

```
select count(distinct v.so_number)
from . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead of `SELECT s1.so_number`.

You don't need to use `COUNT(DISTINCT so_number)`, since `UNION` automatically removes duplicates from the result.

There's also no need to use both `LIKE '%government%'` and `LIKE '%gov%'`. If a string contains `government`, it must also contain `gov`.

Comment: … but the aggregate is part of each single select which is calculated *before* the `UNION`...

Comment: @WolfgangKais There's no aggregation in the individual selects.

Comment: Those 2 queries can produce different results.  I thought the same at first, but you have to count each potential column, not count on 1 column only.  See this demo for what I mean: http://rextester.com/NVEWH64179

Comment: @sgeddes You're right, I didn't think of the case where a single row contributes multiple names to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Harry, 
Below query can be used. Assuming if Bill to name and ship to name has government it need to be considered as 1 row.
Also I believe you are looking for count only.

Apologies, I am not able to add comments hence updating as answer. Let me know if you requirement is different.

```
Select count (billto_name) 
from dbo.lamp_bookings 
where billto_name Like '%government%' or billto_name Like '%gov%' or shipto_name Like '%government%' or shipto_name Like '%gov%'  or soldto_name Like '%government%' or soldto_name Like '%gov%' or end_user Like '%government%' or end_user Like '%gov%';
```

Regards
Jana

Comment: This isn't removing duplicate names from the different columns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes you are right...either billto, shipto, enduser, soldto has any of the search terms like 'government', 'army', 'department','ministry' and each search term is considered only considered once.   The code ypu mentioned worked but there are almost 8 search terms need to be added in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You should put all where conditions in one big block. Then your don't need a subselect.
It would also get rid of duplicates.

If, for example, end_user and billto_name both match the search string but are not exactly the same, then this row would be counted twice. I assume you don't want that. Because "union" would not merge them together, since it only merges exact duplicate rows.

Also, '%gov%' matches '%government%'. You could leave all the longer search strings away. But I am not sure if this is always possible in your overall use case.

Comment: Thanks for reply, could you please help me in writing the code